# Angular custom directive: a strange error occurs when set controller attribute to `function(scope){}`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

When I wrote a custom directive, a strange error blocks me.

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])
.directive('cyMenu', ['RecursionHelper', function(RecursionHelper) {
    function postLink(){};
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/component/cy-menu.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        require: '?^cyMenu',
        controller: function ($scope) { // when set this argument($scope) to scope, error occurs.
            this.getList = function() {
                return $scope.list;
            }
        },
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            isSubmenu: '@'
        },
        compile: function(tElement) {
            return RecursionHelper.compile(tElement, postLink);
        }
    }
}
```

As I pointed out(see comment), when I set `controller` attribute to **`controller: function (scope) {}`**, the error occurs:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: scopeProvider <- scope
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=scopeProvider%20%3C-%20scope
...
```

I don't know why. Any help will be appreciated.

---

**update**

Here is angular's official demo, it looks similar to my directivehttps://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/guide/directive:

```
angular.module('docsTabsExample', [])
.directive('myTabs', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope) {
      ...
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
  };
})
```

Comment: the injection seems to fail because you are trying to do it in the 'controller' argument, it can often bit tricky to do it there. YOu should try to define the controller in a separate file and inject it by name in the 'controller' argument.

Comment: @sam Could you tell me why or explain more detailed? I find the official demo is doing the same: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/guide/directive ---- `myTabs` demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good practice is to separate every component in a separate file, so I would start by putting your controller in a file like that :

```
//File recursionHelperController.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.controllers')
    .controller('RecursionHelperController', RecursionHelperController);

  RecursionHelperController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function RecursionHelperController($scope) {
     //do your stuff
  }

})();
```

Note that I gave you the most correct format I know for a controller or any angular element in general, but you can do something simpler like:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('RecursionHelperController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         //do your stuff
      }])
```

You can then call this controller in your main file :

```
controller: 'RecursionHelperController'
```

Hope it helps

**Update :**

Sometimes the automatic injection has some troubles that's why I recommend doing it this way with an explicit injection. The angular doc only shows the simplest way for clarity and tutorial purposes

**Update 2**

If you don't want to separate the controller, try using the injection safe notation

```
controller : ['$scope', function($scope) {
     //do your stuff
  }])
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In my code, `RecursionHelper` is a service to help handle recursive directive and I split it to another file. But the `controller` is only used to enable my recursive directives can communicate to each other, so I don't want to seprate it. The `Sometimes the automatic injection has some troubles` you wrote may be what I really want.

Comment: Then you should use the explicit injection notation like I just put in update 2 ( or in a few seconds ;) )

Comment: Did my last idea worked ? I ask because  I never tried myself

Comment: Glad to know. Though I honestly never found out why this explicit injection was necessary

Comment: I'm searching details about injection, and if you know something, it'll   be kindful to update this answer and let me know.

Comment: What's more disturbing is that this notation I suggested to use is originally designed to allow minifaction safe process, not for forcing injection. Let me know too if you find something with a comment for example :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66995/discussion-between-sam-and-creeper).